# Debounce in Redux-Toolkit's createSlice()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I am using redux-toolkit's function `createSlice()` to easily create reducers such as:

```js
createSlice({
    ...,
    reducers: {
        action1(state, action) {
            // ...
        }
    }
})
```

At the end of each action, I want to store the current state (for now to local storage, later into a file via electron's IPC). I do not want to write a file each time an action is called, therefore I want to debounce that call.

```js
const save = _.debounce((state) => {/* ... */}, 500);

createSlice({
    ...,
    reducers: {
        action1(state, action) {
            // ...
            save(state);
        }
    }
})
```

The problem is that debouncing creates an async operation and by then, the `immer` proxy (into which the state is automatically wrapped by `createSlice()`) has already been revoked, leading to the error message `illegal operation attempted on a revoked proxy`.

Is there a good way to circumvent this problem? So far, I could only think of using `immer`'s `current` function, but that seems somewhat ugly. I would prefer a solution where the object that was actually produced by the action is passed to the debounced function.

Comment: Have you also tried deboucing `action1`? - `action1: _.debounce((state, action) => {}, 500)`.

Comment: That would debounce the entire update of the state (I first update the state and then save the updated data). Debouncing the entire state update is not what I am looking for.